# Difference in C++ Debug vs Release build results in Visual Studio 2017 Community

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2017, release, visual-studio-debugging

Why is the debug mode build giving different results than release mode build?

```
#define devicecount 4
static const size_t c_maxCount = 4; // I should actually set it to devicecount
bool bstatus[devicecount];
bool cbflag[devicecount];
bool gbflag[devicecount];
#define dpacketlength 9

HANDLE hThreadMain[c_maxCount];
HANDLE hThreadGraph, hThreadComm;

INT WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
    LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    // This snippet for reference only
    // ...
    int i;
    mwnd p[c_maxCount];
    for (i = 0; i < c_maxCount; i++) {
        hThreadMain[i] = CreateThread(NULL, 0, MainThread, &p[i], 0, NULL);
    }
    mwnd g;
    hThreadGraph = CreateThread(NULL, 0, UpdateGraph, &g, 0, NULL);

    mwnd c;
    hThreadComm = CreateThread(NULL, 0, CommThread, &c, 0, NULL);

    // ...
}

// Following thread function has problem
DWORD WINAPI CommThread(LPVOID lParam) {
    char data[(dpacketlength+10)] = { 0 }; // added "+ 10" later
    unsigned int i;
    char pbuf[2];
    bool skip = 0;

    while (1) {
        skip = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < c_maxCount; i++) {
            //Sleep(20); // uncommenting it makes the code work
            if (bstatus[i] == 1) { // device working
                if (cbflag[i] == 0) { // data not ready
                    skip = 1; // skip, flag not set
                }
            }
        }
        //cout << ""; // uncommenting it makes the code work
        if (skip == 1) {
            continue;
        }
        cout << "."; // This is how I measure the program is progressing or not
        // Some code to follow to send data over comm
        // ...
        // assign 9 bytes to data[] (always). 2*4 (always) for 4 devices and 1 extra parameter byte. if maxCount is < 4, the corresponding bytes are zero, as initialized INSHAALLAH.
        for (i = 0; i < c_maxCount; i++) {
            // compute pbuf[]s
            data[(2 * i)] = pbuf[0];
            data[((2 * i) + 1)] = pbuf[1];
        }
        data[8] = (char)par;
        // some code that loops over data[] from data[0] to data[8] and sends bytes over comm
        // ...
        for (i = 0; i < c_maxCount; i++) {
            cbflag[i] = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

I have written this software in Win32 with a console attached for debugging. The code snippet is from a "comm" thread. There are other `c_maxCount` "Main" threads who each have one element of `cbflag[]` assigned.
Those threads check if device is online, if it is, then they grab data and prepare their respective global buffers. Once that is done, they set the respective `cbflag[i]`. They do not touch the buffers until respective `cbflag[i]` is reset to 0.

There is another thread "Graph" which does the drawing on screen in real-time. The Graph thread draws when any one of `gbflag[]` is set (corresponding to each Main thread), and resets the `gbflag[i]` after drawing. The drawing was freezing in release build and I started to debug by putting `cout`s in code. Apparently the Main threads were waiting indefinitely because `cbflag[]`s were not being reset in the third `for` loop of this code at the end of function, as the code was being `skip`ped/ `continue`d. This is when I found out that if I put a `cout` before checking for `skip`, even if it prints empty string, somehow the code works. By "work", I mean the bottom half of code is not `skip`ped. So now I cannot debug without affecting the system.
Also, I tried putting message boxes in the first for loop and before checking for skip, but it still affects the code and it starts working.
If I change `c_maxCount` to 1, it starts working and doesn't skip.
If I uncomment the `Sleep(20)` line, it works and doesn't skip.
However, If I insert a code to assign a value to a variable in place of `cout` or `Sleep()`, it doesn't work, so it does not affect the behaviour.

I've read on stackoverflow that in cases when release application crashes, it mostly has to do with array bounds. I increased the `data[]` array but to no avail.

I have checked the values of `bstatus[]` and `cbflag[]` in the Graph thread by regularly printing to screen in a label, they're 1 for all elements of both arrays.

Comment: Are `MainThread` and `CommThread` supposed to be the same?

Comment: No, they're different.
4 `MainThread`
1 `CommThread`
1 `GraphThread`

Comment: Sinice `cbflag` is modified by one thread and read in another, it should be `std::atomic`.  The compiler may make assumptions about non-atomic global variables (i.e., they aren't modified) that effect a release build that it doesn't make in a debug build.

Comment: I just updated the code for clarity. I 'll look into your suggestion meanwhile INSHAALLAH.

Comment: @speedbooster -- Multithreaded program is much more than starting some threads and using plain old `bool` variables to control things.  It is much more complex than what you may have believed.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm thank you, your suggestion seem to have worked. I undid lots of snippets I had been using to debug and now I have some other problem causing the app to crash in release build. I am trying to figure out what it is. Once I confirm, I'd like to mark the answer.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Could you please point me to the direction to learn? Maybe a resource or a list of topics. I've been coding for quite many years, just not multi-threaded.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm ALHAMDOLILLAH it solved the problem. JAZAKALLAH for the help. Thank you, it worked. Question: Do I have to make a variable atomic if it is being read only in another thread? Or is it only needed to avoid race conditions (writing that is).

P.S. I'm looking for the way to mark your answer as solution, can't seem to find it.

Comment: You can't accept a comment as an answer, but I've created an answer based off of the comment and your reporting that it fixed the problem.

Comment: @speedbooster -- There are many resources on MT programming.  The issue is that it is not a trivial topic -- you have threads, synchronization objects such as mutexes, semaphores, condition variables, atomic variables, etc.  Then you have the issue of debugging these types of programs and coming up with solutions if there is a problem.  A lot more work than plain single-thread programs.  This is why programmers who are well versed in MT programming are highly sought by companies, much more than single-thread-only programmers.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie JAZAKALLAH for pointing me to the right direction. Thank you. They keywords you mentioned would be helpful to look for what I need to learn INSHAALLAH.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `cbflag` is modified by one thread and read in another, it should be `std::atomic`. The compiler may make assumptions about non-atomic global variables (i.e., they aren't modified) that effect a release build that it doesn't make in a debug build.